# Getting tons of errors when compiling a C program

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I was trying to run the following program when this big error occurred. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    char *file = "zahl.txt";
    int fd;
    
    struct flock lock = { F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET, 0, 0, 0 };
    lock.l_pid = getpid();
    fd = open(file, O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
    
    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &lock) != -1)
    //setting the lock to wait while another instance is already running
    {
        FILE *fp1;
        int i;
        char buff[255];
        fp1 = fopen(file, "a+"); //read from file
        while (fgets(buff, 255, fp1) != NULL); //moves to last line of file
        i = atoi(buff);
        i++;
        char temp[10];
        sprintf(temp, "%d\n", i); //printing the incremented value to temp
        fputs(temp, fp1);
        fclose(fp1);
    
        lock.l_type = F_UNLCK;
        fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &lock);
        close(fd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
>  [rmig0489@linux Assign9]$ gcc -Wall -o -g ink ink.c
> ```
>
> ink: In function `_start': (.text+0x0): multiple definition of` _start'
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0):
> first defined here ink: In function `_fini': (.fini+0x0): multiple definition of` _fini'
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0):
> first defined here ink:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of
> `_IO_stdin_used' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here ink: In function` __data_start': (.data+0x0):
> multiple definition of `__data_start' /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here ink:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of` __dso_handle'
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtbegin.o:(.rodata+0x0): first
> defined here ink: In function `_init': (.init+0x0): multiple definition of` _init'
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0):
> first defined here /tmp/ccmuhndv.o: In function `main': ink.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of` main'
> ink:/home/scs/licenta/an1/gr712/rmig0489/C-Programm/Assign9/ink.c:6:
> first defined here
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtend.o:(.dtors+0x0): multiple
> definition of `**DTOR_END**' ink:(.dtors+0x8): first defined here
> /usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section,
> --eh-frame-hdr ignored. /usr/bin/ld: error in ink(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created. collect2: ld returned 1 exit
> status

Comment: Try compiling with `gcc -Wall -o ink -g ink.c`

Comment: For all options that require a parameter, that parameter must follow immediately after the option. Your command tellS gcc to use filename `-g` as output file and `ink ink.c` as input files.

Comment: Makes sense, I will keep this in mind from now on, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the command line: `gcc -Wall -o -g ink ink.c`

The `-o` argument must be followed by the name of the output file, so `-g` is used for that, and `gcc` sees `ink` (the executable produced by a previous command) as a binary module to link along with the object module compiled from `ink.c` and the C library, hence all the duplicate internal symbols.

Use this command:

```
gcc -Wall -g -o ink ink.c
```

Note also these problems in your code:

- relying on the contents of `buff` after the last call to `fgets()` is incorrect, especially if the file happens to be empty. You should instead convert each and every line successfully read and use the last conversion.
- you must call `fseek(fp1, 0L, SEEK_CUR)` before switching from reading the file to writing to it.
- `char temp[10];` is not large enough to convert all possible `int` values. You should make the array larger and use `snprintf` for safety.